# Looking up a column name in another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

 df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
     {
         "id_1": [1, 1, 2, 2],
         "id_2": [11, 11, 22, 22],
         "value_1": [0.1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.01],
         "value_2": [0.2, 0.2, 0.02, 0.02],
         "value_3": [0.3, 0.3, 0.03, 0.03],
     }
 )
```

that looks like this:

```
    id_1  id_2  value_1  value_2  value_3
 0     1    11     0.10     0.20     0.30
 1     1    11     0.10     0.20     0.30
 2     2    22     0.01     0.02     0.03
 3     2    22     0.01     0.02     0.03
```

and another:

```
 df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
     {
         "id_1": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
         "id_2": [11, 11, 11, 11, 22, 22, 22, 22],
         "value_name": [
             "value_1",
             "value_2",
             "value_3",
             "value_1",
             "value_1",
             "value_2",
             "value_3",
             "value_1",
         ],
     }
 )
```

which looks like this:

```
    id_1  id_2 value_name
 0     1    11    value_1
 1     1    11    value_2
 2     1    11    value_3
 3     1    11    value_1
 4     2    22    value_1
 5     2    22    value_2
 6     2    22    value_3
 7     2    22    value_1
```

How do I get the corresponding `value` (for a given `id_1` and `id_2`) from `df_1` into `df_2`, please? i.e. I want a final data frame should look like this:

```
    id_1  id_2 value_name value
 0     1    11    value_1   0.1
 1     1    11    value_2   0.2
 2     1    11    value_3   0.3
 3     1    11    value_1   0.1
 4     2    22    value_1  0.01
 5     2    22    value_2  0.02
 6     2    22    value_3  0.03
 7     2    22    value_1  0.01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drop the dupe rows by `id` columns then `melt` the dataframe and `merge` with `df_2`

```
c = ['id_1', 'id_2']
df_2.merge(df_1.drop_duplicates(c).melt(c, var_name='value_name'), how='left')
```

Result

```
   id_1  id_2 value_name  value
0     1    11    value_1   0.10
1     1    11    value_2   0.20
2     1    11    value_3   0.30
3     1    11    value_1   0.10
4     2    22    value_1   0.01
5     2    22    value_2   0.02
6     2    22    value_3   0.03
7     2    22    value_1   0.01
```